# Getting Android Alarms Info

Tags: java, android, android-intent

Iv'e created several Alarms using an Intent and BroadcastReciever and placed them in an Array of Intents.
For each Intent Iv'e placed a String as in Intent.PutExtra("info", string); to be shown later as a Toast when Alarm is activated,
and gave each a different requestCode.
But when adding multiple Alarms, the Toast shows EVERY other Alarms' info as well.
MainActivity:

```
Intent newAlarmIntent = new Intent(this,AlarmReceiver.class);
        newAlarmIntent.putExtra("info",editText.getText().toString());
        alarmsArray[alarmCounter]=newAlarmIntent;
        alarm.AlarmListSortAndSetNext(gameArrayList, alarmArray, this,alarmCounter,alarmsArray[alarmCounter]);
```

Alarm Class:

```
 public void CreateNew (Context context, Long alarmTimeAsLong, int counter, Intent intent)
{
PendingIntent pendingIntent;
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, counter, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
AlarmManager manager;
manager = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
manager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, (alarmTimeAsLong),pendingIntent);
Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm Set", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

public void AlarmListSortAndSetNext (ArrayList<Game> gameArrayList,Long[] alarmArray,Context context,int alarmCounter, Intent intent)
{
    Long SystemTimeAsLong = System.currentTimeMillis();
    //Sorting Long Array for NEXT ALARM
    for (int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {if(i<gameArrayList.size()){
            alarmArray[i] = gameArrayList.get(i).getDateAndTimeAsLong();
        }
        else alarmArray[i]= 0L;
        }
    Arrays.sort(alarmArray);
    //Setting next ALARM by Long Size
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
         if (alarmArray[i]>SystemTimeAsLong){
            CreateNew(context,alarmArray[i],alarmCounter,intent);
            alarmCounter++;}
    }}
```

AlarmReceiver:

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{
    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock = pm.newWakeLock((PowerManager.SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP), "TAG");
    wakeLock.acquire();
    String gameInfo= intent.getStringExtra("info");
    Toast.makeText(context, gameInfo, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.bipbip);
    mp.start();
    wakeLock.release();}}
```

QUESTION: How can I make each Intent to have it's on "info"/PutExtra, or any other way to tell which one has been activate?

Answer (score 0):

*** Found the issue ***
I had left the **AlarmListSortAndSetNext** method which initially was supposed to manage the Next Alarm. I no longer have to use this method since I have created multiple Intents. Something in the looping probably created multiple **putExtra**();
Thank you.